# One div in between two others, the two on either side need to hit the edge of the browser

Tags: html, css

Also looking for there to be a small space between the middle div and the two on either side. Middle bar needs to be a fixed width.

This is what I have come up with so far, seems a bit messy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#container {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
#mainBar {
    position: relative;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 406px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: white;
}
#mainBarInner {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 400px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
#leftBar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: red;
}
#rightBar {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -2;
    width: 40%;
    height: 50px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 0px;
    background-color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="leftBar"></div>
<div id="mainBar"><div id="mainBarInner"></div></div>
<div id="rightBar"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone confirm whether there is a better way to do this, without having the divs aligned to the left and right and going under the middle div?

Demo file: [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6gw4d0tu/)

Comment: This is too broad in its current state- can you narrow with any specific requirements / limitations? Otherwise, if it seems to meet your requirement its a bit more like code review- there are potentially many ways to produce the required outcome

Comment: Can you please ask a clear question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way, using just percentages for width so it will be pretty responsive.  You may want to include a Reset.css file and then add margins / padding manually.  (These percentages can be adjusted to your liking).  [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ew7127pp/).

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#container {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
margin-top: 50px;
}
#mainBar {
width: 39.5%;
height: 50px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: red;
}
#leftBar, #rightBar {
display: inline-block;
width: 29.5%;
height: 50px;
background-color: red;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
<div id="leftBar"></div>
<div id="mainBar"></div>
<div id="rightBar"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

I guess it is also important to determine what you'd like the middle and side bars to do at different heights... disappear, slide above or below, adjust by percent.  Do you want the middle bar to be a fixed width?  Or a percent on smaller screens but a max-width on larger screens?  With some more specifics we can provide more specific answers.